# Could someone give me an example of image uploader from URL?

Tags: php, jquery

I am using this Image Upload and Cropping with PHP and Jquery: [9lessons.info](http://www.9lessons.info/2011/06/image-upload-and-cropping-with-php-and.html) Maybe someone can give me please PHP script or link to script that allows me upload image from URL?

Comment: `file_put_contents('image.jpg', file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/image.jpg'));`. Needs error checking of course, but the basic idea should work.

Comment: It's doesn't work. I have image fetcher and image cropper. When I crop selected image PHP saves it in uploads directory, but that image is without colors- black.

Comment: So are you saying you have a problem with your cropping code?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that re-sizing images using GD can be buggy, especially when you're dealing with transparency. It could also just be that your script bugs out after it's created the image but before it's copied any data into it.

Go over it step-by-step and see when the image turns black.

Comment: I'm getting error:  Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(uploads/) [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in... AND Warning: imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in....

Comment: That second error appears on ajax_image.php line 20 where is imagecopyresampled($nimg,$im_src,0,0,$x1,$y1,$nw,$nh,$w,$h); First error shows up, I think... because there is some problem with folder permissions.

Comment: "uploads/" is not a path to a file, hence `imagecreatefromjpeg` returns false instead of an image resource.